# lighthouse tab is not presenting in chrome devTool

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I have installed ***lighthouse*** extension in chrome browser recently. But I can neither find it in the dev tool tab nor add it tho.

Here is the screenshot of how the dev tool looks like:
[image]

Do you have any clue how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the extension, it's old and no longer needed. Then reopen devtools and use the built-in Lighthouse. If the panel won't re-appear, it may be moved into the bottom drawer (press Esc to show it).

Comment: @wOxxOm, It works, thanks for you suggestion :)